# Summing positive elements of each row of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I want to sum all the positive elements of each row of `A`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[0,-2,3],[1,0,6],[7,8,0]])
B1=[]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    B=np.sum(A[i]>0)
    B1.append(B)
print(B1)
```

The current output is

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

The expected output is

```
[3,7,15]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to mask the negative values:

```
np.where(A>0, A, 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Or the `where` parameter of [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
np.sum(A, axis=1, where=A>0)
```

Output: `array([ 3,  7, 15])`

Comment: The `where` parameter version needs an `out` parameter as well.