# Delete positive elements of each row except diagonal elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I want to delete all positive elements of a row and replace it with zero but not the diagonal elements. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,-2,3],[1,2,6],[-7,8,-2]])
A=np.delete(np.where(A>0, A, 0).sum(axis=1))
print(A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A=np.delete(np.where(A>0, A, 0).sum(axis=1))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in delete

TypeError: _delete_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```

The expected output is

```
array([[1,-2,0],[0,2,0],[-7,0,-2]])
```

Comment: why did you `sum` in your example? are you the same person who asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75648836/16343464)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy option is to repair the diagonal:

```
B = np.where(A>0, A, 0)
np.fill_diagonal(B, A.diagonal())
print(B)
```

*Note that this creates a new array, while the second approach below modifies A in place.*

Another approach might be to get the x/y indices of the 2D array for which the value is 0 and only keep those not on the diagonal (x!=y):

```
x, y = np.where(A>0)
m = x!=y
A[x[m], y[m]] = 0
```

Output:

```
[[ 1 -2  0]
 [ 0  2  0]
 [-7  0 -2]]
```